# Correct way of using @media query

Tags: responsive-design, media-queries, screen-orientation

I want to change `height` of banner on different screen sizes, currently i am using below snippet.

```
/* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
@media only screen and (min-width : 1366px) {

}

/* Medium Devices, Desktops */
@media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {

}

/* Small Devices, Tablets */
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {

}

/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
@media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {

}

/* Custom, iPhone Retina */ 
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {

}
```

But this code is creating problems, when i change the `height` of banner it change it for bigger screens also.

Now, i googled for this and found different answers and viewpoints of people regarding media query snippet. Below is what working for me, but it is fixed size and i have seen people are not generally using fixed ranges they are using `max` or `min` size only.

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 340px) and (max-device-width : 355px) {}
```

I want to know what is the correct and future-proof way of working with media queries.?

Answer (score 0):

Refer below link and you will find the media queries for almost all the devices. That's correct way as well.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/